# I would like to find Goodness-of-fit between my differential equation simulation result and observed field data. How to find it?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, differential-equations

I modelled a ecological system using ordinary differential equation. Simulated the model for 12 months. I also have 12 months of field data. Now I want to find the goodness of fit between my model simulation and observed data. How to test this?
N.B. The model is non-linear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare fits between models, you may use the mean square error:
$$
MSQE = \frac{1}{df} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-f(t_i))^2
$$
Where $df$ is the number of degrees of freedom (number of data points - number of parameters); $n$ is the number of data points, $y_i$ is the $i$<sup>th</sup> observed measurement (from the field data), that occurred at time $t_i$; and $f(t_i)$ is the estimate you have at time $t_i$ from the ordinary differential equation.

This assumes that the time measurements are *exact*.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. Can you please help me more?
If there any upper limit of MSQE for a particular df as Chi square have, so that I can know that my model is good to fit if calculated MSQE is below that value.